# VPython Error on Ubuntu 11.10

Tags: python, graphics, ubuntu, installation, vpython

I get an error when trying to use [VPython](http://vpython.org/contents/download_linux.html) on Ubuntu 11.10. I installed the program using the Ubuntu Software Center. All the additional instructions that I've found are either for much older versions or confuse me. What do I need to do in order to use VPython? I am running Python 2.7.2.

```
neil@neilcomp:~$ python
Python 2.7.2+ (default, Oct  4 2011, 20:06:09) 
[GCC 4.6.1] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from visual import *
>>> sphere()

(python:26388): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap",

(python:26388): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap",

(python:26388): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap",

(python:26388): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap",

(python:26388): GdkGLExt-WARNING **: Cannot open \xa0\u0003G\u0001

(python:26388): GdkGLExt-WARNING **: Cannot open P\u000d\x99\u0001

glibmm-ERROR **: 
unhandled exception (type std::exception) in signal handler:
what: Unable to get extension function: glCreateProgramObjectARB even though the extension is advertised.

Trace/breakpoint trap
```

Comment: You might try [ubuntu](http://askubuntu.com/) and/or [su]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems like the problem is openGL related.

Try updating your graphics driver (make sure you have 3D acceleration enabled)

Also try installing the dev package for libgtkglextmm-x11, someone on the [ubuntu forums](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1495229) seem to have solved their problem this way.

Comment: `sudo apt-get install libgtkglextmm-x11-1.2-dev` did the trick. Thanks!